# Probability with deck of cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are 2 Players A,B and 32 cards with four colors(say R, G, Y, B) and each color has only one King. Both players pick the card(without putting it back) in turn and first player to pick King of R wins the the game and game ends. A starts first.

If after 4 rounds none of them choose King of R, ***nobody wins and game wins***.

Now the question is. What is the probability that A wins the game?

My Answer: $1/32 + (31/32 * 30/31 * 1/30) + (31/32 * 30/31 * 29/30 * 28/29 * 1/28) + (31/32 * 30/31 * 29/30 * 28/29 * 27/28 * 26/27 * 1/26)$

Am I right or is there any flaw in my logic? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Let's say $A$ picks first.  So in the four rounds, if it goes that long, $A$ will choose the cards in the first, third, fifth, and seventh slots.  Now the special card has a $\frac 1{32}$ probability of being in any particular slot, hence the probability that the special card is in one of $A's$ four slots is $\frac 4{32}=\frac 18$, so that is your answer.

Comment: Players don't put card back to the deck after pulling it out.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that.

Comment: @rajendra  Your own calculations yield the same answer.  Each of the four terms yields $1/32$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Sorry. But I am confused now, How can the probability always remain 1/32 even after removing cards from deck?

Comment: The special card starts in some position in the deck..  Presumably you assume that the deck has been shuffled to ensure that it is equally likely to be in any given position, hence it has a $\frac 1{32}$ probability of being in any particular position.  That position already determines the winner of your game.

Comment: As a numerical illustration, presumably you agree that the probability the top card is the special one is $\frac 1{32}$, yes?  Let's get the probability that the second card is the special one.  Following the method you used you need the top card to be ordinary ($\frac {31}{32}$) and the second to be the special one out of the remaining $\frac 1{31}$.  Thus you would get $\frac {31}{32}\times \frac 1{31}=\frac 1{32}$.